# Reading Database File from External Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

So, this program downloads a file from firebase storage,
my downloading code is:

```
private void downloadFiles(Context context, String fileName, String destinationDirectory, String url) {
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, String.valueOf(destinationDirectory), fileName);

    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}

public void downloading(final String name) {
    downloadRef = storage.getInstance().getReference().child(name);
    downloadRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            String url = uri.toString();
            downloadFiles(Main2Activity.this, name,  getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), url);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Failed!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

and then I want to use this database so I tried to open it with:

```
database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, 0);
```

How can I solve this one? It would be really helpful guys.

Answer (score 0):

I thought your problem was accessibility.
That's why I brought a activity back to get permission from the user.
You test this code

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name", arrayList.get(position));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: it's API 29, I also realized that there may be a problem with my path, so do you know how to write proper path, I can reach the file manually from Files / SDK Built x86 / Android / data / projectName / files

Comment: can you send your code to my email address? maybe i can help you

Comment: okeyy, but I couldn't find your email, here is mine for you to contact me, I'll answer it as soon as I can: k.burak02@outlook.com

Comment: javaddehban1@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` which returns the current state of the primary shared/external storage media. It cannot be used to get the path as string of any file. Use  `context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` to get the string value of the path to the `Download` directory.

Comment: hey, I tried what you have told me to try, and it actually worked, but there is still a problem with reaching that file. I can use:
`File file = new File(path) `

but I can't use it with database, i tried:
`database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, 0);`

it works perfect with files but not with databases